# how to get last three filename of user from mysql server in android

Tags: android

this is my code. i want to get the last three file sent by user on mysql server,i am getting the all file of user by this code but i want to get last three file.on server side id is autoincremented so every time user gets new id ,i had ialso tried to get the largest three id of user by this i can get the file of user but that was unsucessfull.

```
public class ABC extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//            Date d = new Date();
//            Log.e("dip",""+d);
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MMMM d, yyyy ", d.getTime());
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.synergyb.com/dev/abcd.php");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            try {
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1"), 8);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String ab = null;
            try {
                while ((ab = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(ab + "\n");
                    data = sb.toString();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("data", data);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    username = jsonObject.getString("username");


                    dat = jsonObject.getString("Date");
                    Log.e("date", dat);
                    String dattt = s.toString();
                    if (username.matches(str5)) {
                        if (id ==8 && id ==18) {

//                        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
//
//                                list.add(id);
//
//                        Collections.sort(list);
//                   list.get(list.size() - 1);
//
////                        Integer data = list.get(1);
//                        Log.e("dd",""+list);
//                        System.out.println(list.get(list.size()-2));
//                        if (id==list.get(list.size()-2))

                            filename = jsonObject.getString("filename");
                            Model m = new Model(filename);
                            l.add(m);
                            Log.e("filename", filename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            CustomAdapter adapter= new CustomAdapter(History.this, R.layout.activity_main, l);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
```

Comment: i got the answer edit the server side php code will solve the issues...<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db("database namet",$con);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details where username='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{  $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i got the answer edit the server side php code will solve the issues...
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db("database namet",$con);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details where username='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{  $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);

?>
```